# What is the correct syntax for mysql connection with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to developing and am studying to improve.
I have been struggling with the correct syntax for connecting my php page with MySql.
I am not using the "XAMPP default database" ... am using MYSQL WORKBENCH.

Comment: You'd need a MySQL server (as contained in XAMPP), Workbench is "only" a tool for data modeling and administrating your server. Then https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect([server_name], [username], [password]);
```

start with this vanilla code. if it returns true, connection is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Like @brombeer mentioned workbench is a tool for data modelling. you have to create a MySQL server to create a database first. so you can use XAMPP to access the MySQL server and create a database using PHPMyAdmin.

**If you created the database this is how to connect to it using PHP.** 
There are three types of methods available to connect to a database using PHP.

1. MySQLi
2. PDO
3. MYSQL

but MYSQL is not using now due to security issues.

**I will explain how to connect to the Database using MYSQLi**

so here is the dbConection.php

```
    <?php
    function dbConn()
     {
      $dbhost = "localhost";
      $dbuser = "dbUserName";
      $dbpass = "dbUserPass";
      $db = "dbName";
      $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);
     
      return $conn;
     }
     
    function closeConn($conn)
     {
       $conn -> close();
     }
```

Now you can include this file where you need a database connection using `include()` method. Also after you are done with your database operations you can close the connection by calling `closeConn($conn)`.

**Example Code**

```
include("dbConection.php");

$dbConn = dbConn();

// some database operations
// -- --  -- -- -- --
// -- --  -- -- -- --
// after your are done with database operations

closeConn($dbConn);
```